# Naming Multiple files in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and was asked to write a powershell script to create some files and then rename a whole bunch of pdfs in a certain format. The problem is I don't know how to name the pdfs the way I have to. I need to name them 00A to 00F, then after that 0A1-10, 0AA-F, 0B1-10, 0BA-F, 0C1-10 and so on. Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly is the problem with this? You can rename files by using `Rename-Item`. 
Example:

```
Rename-Item C:\file.pdf 00F.pdf
```

If you want to count up in your code do it in decimal and then convert it to hex:

```
'{0:X3}' -f 15 #would give 00F
```

Example using `Rename-Item` in conjunction with the HEX String format (assuming `$i` as your counter):

```
Rename-Item C:\file.pdf "$('{0:X3}' -f $i).pdf"
```